# Generator Connection

Tags: electrical, outdoor, generator

I picked up a used 10kva (45a) Generac unit and want to get it connected thru the transfer switch. Just looking for some feedback on how to get it connected. I was going to use 1" schedule 40 indoors for runs of the 6-3 NM-B (about 75' total) and four 14 ga THHN control wires in a separate 1/2" schedule 40, switching to schedule 80 before it goes outdoors. Then have a type LB on the exterior, then run the control wires directly to the generator and have the 6-3 going to a disconnect box. After the disconnect I was going to use either more schedule 80 or non-metallic flexible conduit with watertight connectors to the generator. As you can see, everything is above ground.

So my questions are:

- Use schedule 80 to the generator or the flex?
- Is NM-B OK in the conduit above ground?
- Where should the disconnect go?
- I had planned to bring the electric outside about 18" to the right of the gas going into the house. Is that OK to be behind the gas line attached to the brick?
  [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You seem to know a fair bit about conduit. So why are you putting cable in it and not THWN?  Not least, outdoors you need 6/3UF which requires 2” conduit.  In THWN you only need #8 for 50A.  4x#8 + 4x#14 is an easy fit inside 1”.

Comment: Why do you want a transfer switch with that large gen set why not a mechanical setup 100$ verses 1500.00 for auto, based on your knowledge. Nmb inside to outside NO not code compliant. Schedule 80 always ok , flex may be needed close to the generator. . A bit more info is needed and I can provide code references and examples as I have done this a time or two. It is awesome you have a proper gas supply with the flex +++

Comment: Can you post photos of your electric panel(s) please? We'll need to know how things are laid out on that side of the ball in order to give you good advice as to how to wire your transfer system

Comment: I added additional pics in the original. Transfer switch was included - just has 4 control wires in the lower left of the switch that go out to the unit. I was going to use the #6 just for future proof. Install instructions says to use separate conduit for power/controls.

Comment: We just had service upgraded to 200a, previously was 60a so panel is wide open. Sub-panel would have water pump, sump pump, water heater, furnace, kitchen outlet and freezer outlet.

Comment: @andyknas -- how many HP are the water and sump pumps, and is the water heater electric or gas? (Also, I presume the water pump is 230V and the sump pump is 115V, right?)

Comment: Not sure on water pump. Single sump 115v. Water heater is gas. Just elec for a blower.